# TCP socket response time in real-time Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a real time project on my Debian Wheezy (with real-time patch), it needs a strong reactivity using TCP communication protocol.

When I send a request, the response time is too long (220us) and I don't understand why.
My problem is when I send a request, my application server answers too late for my needs.

So, I decided to write a short program using TCP socket to acquire my server's response time. (see code below)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char sendBuffer [] = "OK";
    char buffer [10];
    int socket1;
    int workingSocket;
    socklen_t len;

    int nodelay = 1;

    struct sockaddr_in sa1;
    struct sockaddr sa2;
    socket1 = 0;
    workingSocket = 0;

    len = sizeof(sa1);
    memset(&sa1, 0, len);

    sa1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    sa1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa1.sin_port = htons(12345);

    socket1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(socket1, (struct sockaddr *)&sa1, len);

    listen(socket1, 10);

    workingSocket = accept(socket1, &sa2, &len);

    setsockopt (workingSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &nodelay, sizeof(nodelay));

    // receive and send message back
    while (1)
    {
        recv(workingSocket, buffer, 5, MSG_WAITALL);

        send(workingSocket, sendBuffer, 2, 0);
    }
}
```

I check the response time doing the following procedure :

- start a wireshark session to trace the network traffic
- launch my C server.
- send a TCP request for example :  $echo 'abcde'|netcat 192.168.0.1 12345

I got a response time of around 200 µs between the moment the string is sent (abcde) and the moment when I receive the reponse on the socket (OK)

This time seems to be very high. I made the same experience on VxWorks and got a response time aproaching 10µs.

Is the Linux kernel really slow or is there a trick to increase the reactivity of the system ?

Thank you for your help and your advices.

Comment: You can increase your process priority, but Linux isn't really a real-time kernel so a kernel like VxWorks is always going to be more responsive.

Comment: You got a server to respond in 10us? Impressive!  10G LAN?

Comment: Note that if you want guaranteed (hard-real-time) response under Linux, you might investigate Xenomai (www.xenomai.org).  It's non-trivial, but it does work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Curently my process is in a high priority (higher than all others). I made some tests with various priorities and the result is the same.

Comment: @MartinJames Only 1GB LAN. ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'll inquire on this solution for my future projects. I have chosen a real-time patch because it was easier to use and it fills my needs, but it might be better to use another solution.